# SQL Sever Agent Logging

Tags: ssis-2012

I have created a SQL Server agent job called TestJob which executes an SSIS package called CommunityPackage.dtsx.

I have also configured "SQL Server Logging" to sysssislog table for the SSIS package, however when I execute the job nothing is being logged in the sysssislog table?

Is there anything I can do to configure so that when I execute the SQL Server agent job which in turn executes the SSIS package to capture the log in the sysssislog table?

Comment: have you properly selected the events you want to log and audit ? check [this article](http://sqlwithmanoj.com/2011/06/15/logging-in-ssis-using-sql-server-log-provider/) as reference.

Comment: hi kin, I am sure I have properly selected the events because When I execute the package from visual studio, the logs are captured, but if the same package is run through sql server agent nothing is captured in sysssis log table,